# My C code. How to prevent numbers in columns to repeat?

Tags: c

**Hi, I have a question. I want to print a list of odd numbers from 1 to 99 in 2 columns using C, but as you can see in the image, the numbers are repeating. I want the numbers to follow the sequence. Like: 1-3-5-7etc..., not 1-3-3-5-5-7... Hope someone can help me, thank you.**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  int sum=0,i=1,k=0;
  printf("List of odd numbers:\n");
  while(i<99){
    k=i;
    i=i+2;
    printf("%d\t%d\n",k,i);
  }

  for(i=1;i<=99;i++){
    if(i%2!=0)
       sum+=i;
  }

  printf("Sum is: %d",sum);
  return 0;
}
```

[This is the link image of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9J27U.png)

Comment: in your head run that first loop 2 times. I mean first with k = 0 and i = 0, then next loop round, what values do k and i have

Comment: It's printing that because that's what `printf("%d\t%d\n",k,i);` prints.

Comment: I see. So how should I write the loop to avoid that?

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= 99; i += 2)` is a way to loop over odd numbers `1 - 99` (inclusive)

Answer (score 1):

Print your current number and the next number (+2). Afterwards, increment the current number by two positions (+4).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    for (unsigned i = 1; i < 99; i += 4)
        printf("%d\t%d\n", i, i + 2);
}
```

`stdout`:

```
1   3
5   7
9   11
13  15
17  19
21  23
25  27
29  31
33  35
37  39
41  43
45  47
49  51
53  55
57  59
61  63
65  67
69  71
73  75
77  79
81  83
85  87
89  91
93  95
97  99
```